# Output of syslog, sent to stdout, grepped, is getting truncated mid-line

Tags: grep, syslog

So I'm logging some debug information, sending it to stdout whereupon I grep it for a string. At a certain point, logging is done and the application is waiting for stuff, but grep's output is truncated mid-line. So it matched a line, but didn't output all of that line.

Is there a way to force grep to flush?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
It appears that --line-buffered will help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you solved your problem with grep by using the --line-buffered flag.  Also make sure that your application is flushing your stdout after each line.  If your stdout is a terminal, line buffering is the default but when you pipe it into another program the default is to use full buffering.

If you are piping data into a program that doesn't have the --line-buffered flag (like uniq for example), take a look at the stdbuf program (http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/stdbuf-man.html) which allows you to modify the buffering options of any program.

See http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ for a good overview of the issue and some common solutions.